# What does triple colon (:::) in a data type mean in haskell?

Tags: haskell

What does triple colon (:::) in a data type mean in Haskell?

For example:
`data Term = Var ID | Atom String | Nil | Term:::Term`

Which is found in this paper https://gup.ub.gu.se/file/207634

How would it be used?

For example, I can do `foo = Var "hello"` but I don't know what use `Term:::Term` would be.

Comment: It is the data constructor.

Comment: i spot this trick in optparse-generic documentation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(:::)` is the name of the data constructor. You can thus define the `Term` type with:

```
data Term = Var ID | Atom String | Nil | (:::) Term Term
```

so just like you have `Var`, `Atom`, and `Nil` as data constructors, `(:::)` is a data constructor as well. This data constructor takes two parameters which both have `Term` types. A list has `(:)` as data constructor for example.

Data constructors can be a sequence of symbols, given these start with a colon (`:`), and given it is not a reserved operator like `:`, `::`, etc. This is specified in the [*Syntax reference* of the Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html):

> ```
> consym        →   ( : {symbol})⟨reservedop⟩
> reservedop    →  .. | : | :: | = | \ | | | <- | -> |  @ | ~ | =>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Would it be clearer with GADT syntax?

```hs
data Term :: Type where
  Var   :: ID -> Term
  Atom  :: String -> Term
  Nil   :: Term
  (:::) :: Term -> Term -> Term
```

These signatures match the output of `:kind` and `:type`:

```
>> :k Term
Term :: *
>> :t Var
Var :: ID -> Term
>> :t Atom
Atom :: String -> Term
>> :t Nil
Nil :: Term
>> :t (:::)
(:::) :: Term -> Term -> Term
```

Comment: "These signatures match the output of `:kind` and `:type` [ *after* you've defined `data Term = Var ID | Atom String | Nil | Term:::Term`] :"